# Get a whole history of changes from JTextArea

Tags: java, swing, jtextarea

There is a possibility to get a list of changes in `JTextArea` in simple way?

I mean that I want to retrieve all text which were typed/showed in `JTextArea`, something like ReDo/UnDo. Have the possibility to back, like "CTRL + Z"

Comment: Are you able to better define 'changes' please?

Comment: as far as i know , no API handles that , you gotta keep the record yourself . store in some temp file or data base

Comment: Attaching a dedicated TextListener that just logs the TextEvent's would be quite simple. Is a TextEvent log sufficient?

Comment: I mean that I want to retrieve all text which were typed/showed in JTextArea, something like ReDo/UnDo. Have the possibility to back, like "CTRL + Z"

Comment: http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Swing-JFC/SimpleGUIdemoofUndoManagerandfriends.htm very helpfull

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Back in the days I have used UndoManager to manage swing text component changes.

You can find api here: [Oracle JavaDoc UndoManager](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/undo/UndoManager.html)

And usage example here: [Java2s example UndoManager](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0240__Swing/AddingUndoandRedotoaTextComponent.htm)

HTH

---

**Update**:

*UndoManager* extends *CompoundEdit* which declares a protected Vector "***edits***" of UndoableEdit objects.

You could get access to that Vector, for listing changes, by writing a class that extends UndoManager and provides public getter metod list getChangesVecor.

Comment: textcomp is a JTextArea, I want to have a redo listening JTextArea but have ReDo/UnDo buttons.

Answer (score 1):

If you are after changes in the text of the area you could try one of the following:

Add some form of listener to the JTextArea and each time the text changes store the information as a String in an arrayList, although if you are expecting anything more than a small amount of changes this solution will likely be highly inefficient.

Probably the better option, store the information in a text file/database.  This creates a permanent record/log of the information, and could then be read by future programs if required.

Good luck!